# Magento: How to add a custom attribute while adding a product to cart?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have "Size" as a custom attribute for products. The question is, how can I add the size data while adding a product to the cart and checkout, so when the admin sees the order, he becomes aware of this information?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you adding your product into the cart?

Comment: With a form and a button: <button type="button" class="btn-add-cart button" title="" onclick="<?php echo 'productListForm'.$_product->getId().'.submit()'; ?>"></button>

Comment: Is you `size` attribute configured as `required`?

Comment: Then it is something wrong with your installation because normally Magento will not allow to add a product into cart w/o choosing required attribute.

Comment: I only want to add the size data when adding a product to the cart. Should I add a select field? Should I name it size?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18015/discussion-between-felipe-pena-and-tim)

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways.

1. Use custom options. For `size` this will not apply correctly (I'll explain why below), but for some kind of data it could be particularly useful (e.g. save *logo placement* or other attribute which can not be represented by a physical item). For custom option tutorial you can use [this link](http://www.magentoadvisor.com/magento-backup/complex-magento-products-part-2-simple-products-with-custom-options/).
2. Use Configurable product. For attributes like `size` or `colour` it's the best option. It has few benefits compared to *custom options* - automatic stock management for your **options**, ability to assign different pictures, and you don't need to recreate the whole set of options for different products. Here's the official tutorial -> [tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know I can achieve this with configurable products, but I have hundreds of them and I would like use an easy path at the moment. Is there any way I can save the size selected with only a custom attribute?